# Shell: script.sh is writing empty files

Tags: shell, ansible

I have a playbook:

```
---
- name: Preparing the diff file (show | compare)
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: "Creating a diff file"
    shell: "{{config_dir}}/diff.sh"
```

And a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#find . -size +0 -name diff -printf "\n%p\n" -exec cat {} \; > $HOME/diff.all
#find . -size +0 -name diff -printf "\n%p\n" -exec cat {} \; > mytest.beep
more */diff | less > doop
```

The task starts the script, the script grabs all the files named "diff" and shoves their content into test.txt.

When I run this command in the shell, it works.

When I run this script, it works.

When I run this playbook, it creates text.txt but the file is always empty.

I tried different scripts with the same goal.

I tried adding the file creation through Ansible instead of inside the script:

```
  tasks:
  - name: "Creating a diff file"
    shell: "{{config_dir}}/diff.sh > test.txt" (Also tried with >>)
```

I tried adding become: true

Every time, my playbook ran successfully, test.txt was created, but it's always empty.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Comment: You expect `more` and `less` to behave in a reasonable way when not connected to a TTY? Simply put, that's an expectation not backed by documented behavior of these tools. `cat */diff > test.txt`

Comment: ...beyond that, `set -x` is your friend. If your script runs `exec 2>/path/to/log.txt; set -x`, then it'll log what it's trying to run in... well... `log.txt`.

Comment: On a different point, `.sh` extensions are bad form: The UNIX `execve()`-style syscall gives a minimal-dependency way to interface between programs that means that the caller doesn't need to know or care what language the callee is written it. When you put language information in the filename, then you mean that you either need to change all the callers when you rewrite the callee in a different language, or you end up with programs named `.sh` but written in non-shell languages.

Comment: Oh -- and be sure you have a shebang on your scripts. You can get away without one when your script is being invoked by an interpreter that makes assumptions when the operating system fails to do an exec itself, but that's not always true; the Right Thing is to always use a shebang, and not need to guess around when things do and don't work.

Comment: Ok, I am using a Shebang. This is the full script:

Comment: Edit your question, rather than putting that into a comment.

Comment: Yeah, this editor is driving me nuts.

Comment: ...so, as-edited, I stand by my prior comments. Use `cat`, ditch `more` and `less`.

Comment: And as my earlier comment, I used different versions of the script. `find . -size +0 -name diff -printf "\n%p\n" -exec cat {} \; > mytest.beep`

Comment: Charles, I'm not sure you're being more than mean.  I've used more|less for more than a decade to format output, trivially, for example.


And Less, here, is kinda extra, but less was built to just pass things through when run in that fashion; and it's obvious the script has gone through a few simplifications as avenues are being tested.  


I think the pipe and redirect are being gobbled up . Maybe try encapsulating that in a single quote.

Comment: @Quake, have you collected a stderr log with `set -x`, as I suggested above? Right now there's not much actual *evidence* to go on.

Comment: @user2066657, ...I retract my statements only inasmuch as POSIX `more` (but not GNU `less`) has well-defined behavior when stdout is not to a TTY. Other than that, I don't believe anything I've said here has been incorrect; less *may* have behavior equivalent to `cat` with non-TTY stdout, but without explicit documentation to that effect, it also may not -- and without standard-defined behavior alternate implementations (busybox, etc) are free to deviate as they choose.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy

I tried it this way: more */diff | less > test; set -x

I still get an empty file.

However I ran ansible with -v and found that the problem was caused by the script running in the wrong directory. I added a chdir to the shell call in my playbook and it's working now. I'm still new to Linux and it's not yet a reflex to start using -v everywhere.

Comment: `set -x` needs to be BEFORE the commands you want to debug, not after them.

Answer (score 1):

The script was running in the wrong directory. It was easy to debug by adding -v to the ansible-playbook command.